# Choosing the right number of Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I have the following python code:

```
results = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=600).map(update_db, records_to_add)
```

When this runs htop shows 115% CPU. Does that mean I should dial back the number of workers so it is below 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`115%` means that more than 1 core is doing the work, it does not mean all your cores are over `100%`. 
If you had a dual-core machine and you'd have them at full load it could show something near `200%` for example

Comment: I have 16 cores. so should i aim for just under 1600%?

Comment: Whatever makes your code run the fastest would be good I'd say.